# How to set height of textblock/textbox to 3 lines?

Tags: wpf, textblock

I can set fixed height in pixels, but i'd like to set it in lines. Sort of like in html you can set height of an textarea to number of rows/lines.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Try `3em`

1em is equal to the current font size. 2em means 2 times the size of the current font. E.g., if an element is displayed with a font of 12 pt, then '2em' is 24 pt.

Comment: Does that take leading (WPF calls it LineHeight, iirc) into account? If not, then you maybe have less than three lines.

Comment: according to MSDN only px, in, cm, pt is allowed, no em

Comment: perhaps you can convert it somehow

Answer (score 16):

For a TextBox, set the MinLines and MaxLines properties.  To better approximate an HTML textarea, consider also setting TextWrapping, VerticalScrollBarVisibility, and AcceptsReturn as follows:

```
<TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" AcceptsReturn="True" MinLines="3" MaxLines="3"/>
```

Comment: Min lines sets the minimal number of lines you will always see, the Max lines is the maximal number of lines shown, then activate the scrollbar to see additional lines.

Answer (score 2):

### Solution 1

You could FormattedText to measure the size of text, here is an example:

```
String text = "Here is my text";
Typeface myTypeface = new Typeface("Helvetica");
FormattedText ft = new FormattedText(text, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, 
        FlowDirection.LeftToRight, myTypeface, 16, Brushes.Red);

Size textSize = new Size(ft.Width, ft.Height);
```

### Solution 2

Use the Graphics class  (found [here](http://blog.lexique-du-net.com/index.php?post/2009/05/28/Create-a-poster-to-add-it-in-your-Mogre-Scenestrong) ):

```
System.Drawing.Font font = new System.Drawing.Font("Calibri", 12, FontStyle.Bold);
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(1, 1);
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
SizeF measureString = g.MeasureString(text, font);
```

Here you are !